# Why has Namor joined the X-men?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, avengers, avengers-vs-x-men

In the Avengers vs X-men preview, the line-up shows Namor as an x-man, and indeed he's in the preview comic! I did some research and it turns out Xavier and Magneto have long (since 1964!) suspected him to be a mutant, and that Emma Frost requested him to join in *Dark Reign*, but why would he stay? I thought Namor had an undersea kingdom to be arrogant over?

Comment: He's been a member of both teams (among others) at various times; usually in times of exile or peril. Why he would have chosen to ally with the X-men over the Avengers must be ideological, but I don't know. A good question.

Comment: It sounds like he aligned himself with the X-Men during dark reign, I'd really like to know more about this though before april....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [Wikipedia - X-Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men#2000s) is correct (not usually a good citation), at the end of 2009, within the [*Nation X*](http://marvel.com/comic_books/issue/28844/x-men_nation_x_hardcover) story arc, Magneto rejoins X-Men (Uncanny X-Men #516) as leader and Namor joins Magneto & the other X-Men in developing Utopia for both mutants and Atlanteans (Uncanny X-Men #520)

The above arc plot points appear backed, in part, by minor descriptions at marvel.com and other reviews.

If/when forced to pick a side in Avengers vs X-Men, it's very possible that the recent allegiance and co-operation with the X-Men around Utopia within this arc is why he aligns with the X-Men.

Answer (score 2):

Namor is himself a mutant.

In the Fantastic Four story arc "Wolf at the Door," Sue Richards works as a public school teacher. During one scene, she's teaching the class about mutants, and during the lesson, describes Namor as the first mutant.

His flight capabilities, super-strength, and longevity are all results of his mutation.

Comment: @Pureferret I thought this question was about why he would join the X-Men in X-Men vs Avengers not whether he was a [mutant](http://marvel.com/comic_books/series/12761/namor_the_first_mutant_2010_-_present) or not. Being a mutant doesn't put him on the X-Men side automatically does it? *(**not** that my answer is great or right, mind you)**

Comment: I took the question to be asking why he would side with the X-Men, in which case, being a mutant himself would seem like a reasonable answer.

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't disagree, but there's suggestion (based on the [preview cover for #1](http://marvel.com/images/gallery/issue/41188/images_from_avengers_vs_x-men_2011_1/image/903193)) that some mutants are on the Avengers side (notably, Beast and Wolverine). I think the deviation in what we may see as clear cause for allegiance are based on events that preceded, from Utopia, Dark Reign, Nation-X and Schism.

Answer (score 1):

I think somewhere - I don't know quite where - Marvel has confirmed that Namor is indeed an x-gene mutant. His human father was an x-gene carrier and that's why Namor has wings on his feet and is considerably stronger than normal Atlanteans, who themselves are already superstrong to endure the pressure of the deep. In short, he's an Atlantean-human mutant hybrid.